# Is it possible to use one of the two processors for ML acceleration?

Tags: cpu

I have two processors (two different physical processors) with base frequencies 3.2 Ghz and 4.0 Ghz.

 I want to ask if there exist a method which I can use to the 3.2 Ghz processor for ML acceleration ?

 I don't have a good gpu for this task.

 Will it be slower than a GPU ?

Comment: It's not "acceleration", it is just running ML on a CPU. "acceleration" means something faster than a CPU. But surely if you do have two CPUs you can use both.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this fits as an answer to your question

---

It depends on what type of ML you are trying to do.

For example, I don't really know how to parralelize reinforcement learning techniques (most likely there is a way to parralelize at least some of them), but it is simple to parallelize a supervized learning technique that uses *batching* - simply distribute the batch between the two processors, and then aggregate the results.

---

I can't tell you if this will be faster of slower than using GPU, since it really depends on the GPU as well. But taking into consideration that GPUs are good at those kinds of computations, my guess would be that a GPU could still be faster if your supervised model is large.

Comment: Thank you for answer.